# How to prevent Eclipse Plug-in auto build from generating warnings for system files

Tags: ide, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force.com IDE warning that files in .git subdirectory only saved locally, not to server](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/963/force-com-ide-warning-that-files-in-git-subdirectory-only-saved-locally-not-to)

Recently switched to handling version control outside of eclipse and now whenever I return to the project and do something that triggers a project refresh (changing the credentials or selecting file system refresh from the project menu)  the auto-build generates 100s of "File only saved locally, not to server" for system files (i.e. .DS_Store and .git files).  Is there anyway to exclude these from the auto-build?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I think this is basically the same question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/963/154.

Comment: @PeterKnolle that's just what I was looking for!!! Err, shouldn't have missed that :(

Comment: @PeterKnolle, feel free to vote to close this (apparently it takes four votes, not sure if there is a better way to do this)